# Convert Writing to Text in PDF

Tags: pdf

I recently started using a LiveScribe pen. It basically allows me to write notes and then save them to my computer. While this is great, the notes are not actual text, but more like an image of the notebook. How could I, without any additional expenses, convert the PDFs generated by LiveScribe to actual text? Paid software at my disposal include Adobe Creative Cloud and Microsoft Office 365. Thanks for any help.